# CarouselView from AlexRainman not rendering on iOS, fine on Android. Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm having trouble making the CarouselView control from [AlexRainman](https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView). The control is rendered fine on Android, but not on iOS. My project is a Xamarin PCL project for iOS and Android, currently working on Visual Studio 2017 for macOS. And stuck on this, and have no idea how to solve this error. Any help would be appreciated.

My Content Page:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="PelotaJara.BookingUserPage"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions;assembly=CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions"

         >
    <controls:CarouselViewControl x:Name="carousel" IndicatorsTintColor="Gray" ShowIndicators="True"  
                              CurrentPageIndicatorTintColor="Black"  Orientation="Horizontal" InterPageSpacing="10" 
                              VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  AnimateTransition="true" IsSwipingEnabled="true">
        <controls:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="50*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="20*" />

                </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                    <Image Grid.Row="0"  VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                    <Label  Grid.Row="0" Text="Cancha Iluminada"  TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="End"/>
                    <Button Grid.Row="2" Text="Reservar" BackgroundColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="White"/>


            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
        </controls:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
    </controls:CarouselViewControl>
```

The Code-behind:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class BookingUserPage : ContentPage
{   
    ObservableCollection<CarouselModel> model { get; set; }  
    public BookingUserPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();



        model = new ObservableCollection<CarouselModel>();

        carousel.ItemsSource = model;

        model.Add(new CarouselModel("http://seattlerats.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Soccer-Field-Night.jpg"));
        model.Add(new CarouselModel("http://seattlerats.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Soccer-Field-Night.jpg"));
        model.Add(new CarouselModel("http://seattlerats.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Soccer-Field-Night.jpg"));




    }



}

public class CarouselModel
{
    public CarouselModel(string imageString)
    {
        Image = imageString;
    }
    private string _image;
    public string Image
    {
        get { return _image; }
        set { _image = value; }
    }
}
```

The Appdelegate.cs:

```
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {


        ServicePointManager
          .ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
          (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;


        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        LoadApplication(new App());

        CarouselViewRenderer.Init();

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
```

And finally, my MainActivity.cs:

```
    [Activity(Label = "PelotaJara", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {

        ServicePointManager
.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
(sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        CarouselViewRenderer.Init();

        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
}
```

Comment: you can open an issue on GitHb

Comment: What is the problem that you experience on iOS?

Comment: @ user3096081 did you find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

My issue may not be exactly what you are having but here how i solved it: it worked fine on version CarouselView.FormsPlugin 4.4.1 and Xamarin forms 2.3... works fine updated the carousel view to 4.4.3 iOS breaks Android works fine, i submitted an issue on github and seems to have been resolve, so try update it to the latest version and xamarin forms to 2.4.0 should work. here is the issue on github: https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView/issues/210

Answer (score 0):

Your AppDelegate is wrong, it should be:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{


    ServicePointManager
      .ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
      (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;


    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
    CarouselViewRenderer.Init();
    LoadApplication(new App());

    return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}
```